# Submitting selection box item when javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, php, forms, select, submit

This is the case. I want to pass onchange event to a page (actually to the page this call is coming from) without having javascripting available. There is a  tag with address like this:

`<form name='form1' action='http://mysite.com/index.php' method='get'>`

The select tag takes onchange event:

`<select name='alue' onchange='this.form.submit();'>`

I want to pass a particular, restricted list of choices to another selection box, based on the first selection box selection. I would like this to happen when javascript is disabled but is this impossible? Is this totally a client side event? Is there a way to perform this action purely with php (by forcing the page to reload somehow)?

The point is to have an alternative way for user to restrict amount of choices when javascript is disabled. Thank you for any advice and suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is following :

Submit the form generally i.e through submit button then you can check in POST variable if the select box was selected or not.

if select box have value you can pass the form data using PHP to your page.